# TOTALYTD fiscal year, why is third argument necessary?

Tags: powerbi, dax

In my data model I have a custom fiscal calendar (begins on jul-1).

For the YTD calculation, I'm using a measure like:

```
Faturação YTD Fiscal = TOTALYTD(SUM(Factos[Faturação]);'CalendárioFiscal'[Date];ALL('CalendárioFiscal'[Date]);"06/30")
```

This works well, but I don't understand why I need the 3rd and 4th argument, since the function returns the same values without these as long as the fiscal calendar exists.

Are these arguments necessary at all or are they meant to be used if there's no fiscal calendar?

Also, if the 4th argument is there, the 3rd is also mandatory. Why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd and 4th arguments are optional.

The 3rd argument is where you place a filter if you want one.

The 4th argument is a string where define your year-end date. By default (if you don't include the argument), it is December 31st, but if your fiscal year ends June 30, then you need to specify that. You may include the 4th argument without the 3rd argument.

Documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634400.aspx

Comment: Thanks, are these arguments (3rd and 4th) necessary at all or are they meant to be used if there's no fiscal calendar?

Comment: @NunoNogueira The 4th is necessary if your fiscal year doesn't end on Dec 31st.